# NavigationBar to sit on top of the view

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm getting a little confused when it comes to UINavigationBar.
I set it up programatically and what it does is it pushes my viewController down (So things near the bottom of the view that are seen in storyboard are not seen after launching the app)

The question is - is there a way to tell my navigationbar not to push down my view but to sit on top of it instead?

I've been trying to use bounds and frame for this but it did not help.

Playing with self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent did not help neither.

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard, the attributes inspector for the problematic view controller. Disable adjust scroll view insets.

Think this is a bug on apple's part. It occurs very frequently for me.

Comment: Oh c'mon!!! It was really that simple?! I've been trying to figure it out for 2 hours!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Haha I feel your pain